# ensure a sub-string is preceded by an odd quantity of a given character

Tags: php, regex, substring

How can I ensure a given search string (i.e. `xxx`) is preceded by an **odd** quantity of a given character (i.e. `*`)?

```
$string='bla bla xxx bla *xxx bla bla **xxx bla bla ***xxx bla bla ****xxx';
$search='xxx';
$preceding_character='*';
```

desired `$string`

```
$string='bla bla *xxx bla *xxx bla bla ***xxx bla bla ***xxx bla bla *****xxx';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @caCtus  Nothing good.   I know a little regex and could use string_replace, but don't know how to handle the `odd` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with preg_replace_callback(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

```
<?php

$string='bla bla xxx bla *xxx bla bla **xxx bla bla ***xxx bla bla ****xxx';
$search='xxx';
$char='*';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(' . preg_quote($char) . '*)(' . $search . ')/', 
    function($matches) {
        global $char;

        //If even number of $char found, add one
        if(strlen($matches[1]) % 2 === 0) {
            return $matches[1] . $char . $matches[2];
        } else {
            return $matches[0];
        }

    }, 
    $string
);

print $string;
?>
```

Demo here: http://3v4l.org/tZKOF

Comment: i make the same. but some late :) i think regex must begin from `(^|\s+)` else the 1st word will not be matched. And eneded with `\b`

Comment: Thanks Typoheads. A little more complicated than I was hoping, but expect it needs to be so.  May I ask why `$char` needs to be global?

Comment: If it isn't, it will not be available in the callback function.

Comment: @splash58 I think the first word is matched, but I didn't care about testing with word boundaries. Maybe `\b` should be added to make sure that only "**xxx" is replaced, but not "**xxxxxxxx".

Answer (score 1):

you can also do something like this

```
preg_replace("/\s([*]{0}?|((\*\*)+))xxx/", " *$1xxx", $string);
```

or with your variables

```
preg_replace("/\s([{$preceding_character}]{0}?|(([{$preceding_character}]{2})+)){$search}/", " {$preceding_character}$1{$search}", $string);
```

or more precisely:

```
preg_replace("/((^xxx)|(?<=([^*]))xxx|(?<!\*)(\*\*)+xxx)/", "*$1", $string);
```

Comment: @user1032531 it look for even number of `*` with xxx in your string and then appends * to the matched string to make it odd

Comment: Thanks.  Will need to think it over, but it seems perfect.  Also, is `(\*\*)+)` and `([*]{2})+)` the same?

Comment: Ah, I see the pitfall.  Won't match `$` if proceeded by a whitespace.

Comment: @user1032531 can you share what you tried to match, string and regex

Comment: Please see http://3v4l.org/1dbDM  Notice how an even number of `*` not proceeded by a whitespace is not modified.

Comment: @user1032531 i have updated my answer with new regex without any pitfall, try that

Answer (score 0):

```
$string='bla bla xxx bla *xxx bla bla **xxx bla bla ***xxx bla bla ****xxx';
$search='xxx';
$preceding_character='*';

$array_of_strings = explode($search, $string);

foreach ($array_of_strings as $key => $value) { 
    if($value == end($array_of_strings)) break;
    $count_preceding_character = substr_count($value, $preceding_character);
    if($count_preceding_character % 2 == 0) {
         $array_of_strings[$key] = $value.$preceding_character;
    }
}

$final_string = implode($search, $array_of_strings);

echo $final_string;
```